# What is the origin of suffixing "-ass" to adjectives?

Tags: etymology, adjectives, american-english, suffixes, colloquialisms

I am spending one month in the US and it seems that everything is "big ass", "lame ass", and "crazy ass". What is the purpose of modifying every adjective with "ass"? Is this an Americanism or some global trend that I have yet to notice (I don't watch television). Where did this phenomenon begin?

Medicine before the disease: I have seen the [relevant XKCD comic](http://xkcd.com/37/).

---

I just found the article [The -Ass Suffix and Beyond](http://everything2.com/title/The+-Ass+Suffix+and+Beyond) from another EL&U page. It does discuss the phenomenon but does not mention the origin. Is this phenomenon not new?

Comment: This related [question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/185440/where-does-the-slang-word-bad-ass-badass-come-from) has a particularly relevant [answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/194197/2923).

Comment: Also relevant,  the converse of the XKCD: [What is 'ass-door'?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/505968/what-is-ass-door)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It may have begun as part of a few stock phrases, but now I would say *-ass* functions as a generic [intensifier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intensifier).  Colloquial English has a lot of these (one might say an *assload*), often making use of rude or vulgar words for added impact.  One could as easily say *fucking crazy*, *crazy as shit*, *crazy as hell*, *hella crazy*, *crazy as fuck*, *crazy as balls,* or even combine them as *balls-ass crazy*.

Comment: Actually, I have been exposed to people who use this as their normal speech. I do not know what they would say should they ever have the need to get vulgar!

Answer (score 3):

A little [poking around on Google NGrams](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=bad%20ass,badass,fat%20ass,stupid%20ass&year_start=1600&year_end=2008&corpus=0&smoothing=3) around gave 'stupid ass' as the oldest usage of the form I could find (1671). Which makes sense to me since it comes from comparing a person to the animal: Literally "a stupid ass."

The other forms are, I think, just derived from that original usage of 'ass' where other adjectives are substituted for the original 'stupid'. In effect, 'ass' becomes just a vulgar word for 'person'.

Comment: Actaully, I have heard it referred to non-people as well. Just yesterday, I heard a Matzoh referred to as "a big ass cracker".

Answer (score 3):

[Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ass?show=2&t=1321214753) says of adverb *ass*:

> Definition of ASS
>   often vulgar
>   —used as a postpositive intensive especially with words of derogatory
>    implication
>
> Origin of ASS
>   First Known Use: circa 1920

Answer (score 3):

Don't know the origin, but it's been around a long time in Black American dialect, e.g., Charles Mingus' composition "The Shoes of the Fisherman's Wife Are Some Jive Ass Slippers," from his 1972 album "Let My Children Hear Music."

Comment: I think this is the only answer that is on the money in terms of showing clear use as an  intensifying suffix with a dateable attestation.

Comment: Chuck Stone in *King Strut* (1970) uses the phrase " jive-ass honkies".  But I'm pretty sure the phrase had been in use for several years already by that time.

Answer (score 3):

Elaborating on the accepted answer, here is McWhorter in *[Words on the Move](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Words_on_the_Move/vKqTCwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=0)*:

> There is a *big pot* and there is a *big-ass pot*, there is a *lame excuse* and a *lame-ass excuse*. An initial temptation is to think this is simply a matter of profanity. However, that implies that leaving aside the fact that one of them is rude, *big pot* and *big-ass* pot have the same meaning. They don’t.
>
> You can tell from really trying to imagine just any old adjective, any old time, quietly appended with -ass. Even in the most foulmouthed person you can imagine, notice how hard it is to imagine him saying, I saw a *gray-ass* squirrel. If you think about it, he’d say that only if he thought of squirrels of some other color as normal, such that the gray squirrel is a surprise. *Gray-ass squirrel* comes with a backstory:
>
> “Where I come from, squirrels are black, but when I got here, I looked out the window and saw a gray-ass squirrel!” *Gray-ass* doesn’t mean simply “gray as uttered by a potty-mouth,” but “counterexpectationally gray.”
>
> [...]
>
> But to remark on the pot being “really big” implies, in itself, that there was an expectation that it would not be.
>
> Words change, and ass was assigned a mission. A good guess is that it started with *big-ass*, because in language as in so much else, things tend to start with the literal and drift into the abstract, and human beings can literally have large behinds: *Then a big-ass fellow jumped in and settled it once and for all.* However, yes, it would have been *fellow* rather than *guy*, *dude*, or *bro*, because the **counterexpectational *ass* floated beyond anatomical plausibility as far back as 1919, when someone was documented as getting angry when a “silly ass barber shaved my neck.” All manner of *-ass* usages pop up well before 1950: an accent criticized as having “*lousy broad-ass As*,” and familiar-sounding locutions such as *green-ass* (corporals), *poor-ass* (southerners), and *broke-ass* (a waiter).** In all these cases, the point is that the quality in question draws attention.
>
> In narrating, we are creating a little movie. We need to focus the camera or the lights on what we deem worthy of note. We don’t want to only show a waiter, but to remark that he was broke, since it isn’t considered the norm for someone who works to be broke. A real camera could zero in on his frayed cuffs or show him hitching a ride home: in a grand old film noir, the character would not be written as actually stating, “I lack funds.” Talking, we might designate the waiter as broke-ass: “He was working and all, but actually he didn’t have any money.”

So we may say that *ass* is a counterexpectional intensifier; one that goes pretty far back, one that is maybe spreading its wings and moving around the world. I can't attest to BE, but I *have* heard it used in Indian English (surprising, given its relative chastity).

Comment: I don't agree with this at all. You can absolutely get a lame-ass excuse from a flaky friend who consistently and predictably gives bad excuses. It just means the excuse was *particularly* lame, but not necessarily *unexpectedly* so.

Comment: I don't think McWhorter's first example is a valid use of the term - "silly ass", with "ass" having the equine rather than the pygian meeaning, was a common (and not particularly vulgar) expression at the time.

Answer (score 2):

My personal belief is that the first popular formation of this nature was *bad ass*, which people liked because of its strangely onomotapoeic properties, and that the generalized use of "ass" as a suffix formed by analogy from there.  (That is, the existence of one popular idiom of the form "﻿<adjective> ass" created a conceptual space for other constructions of that form to flourish in.)

I would say the phenomenon has been perceptible for maybe the last 25 years, highly visible for the last 15 or so.

Comment: Onomatopoeic? Exactly what sound do bad asses make?

Comment: They Baaaaaah like sheep. (The good ones Bray the way they are supposed to)

Answer (score 2):

I tend to think that *[fat ass](http://books.google.com/books?id=NihEAAAAIAAJ&pg=PA384&dq=%22fat+ass%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=i1SGT9eGMoKY8AGNwMWiCA&ved=0CFkQ6AEwBQ#v=onepage&q=%22fat%20ass%22&f=false)* probably predates *bad ass* although I cannot prove it.
The cited book contains material originally published in 1744 so it dates at least from then.

Comment: I'm certain that's an older established usage, and I'd think that it sort of set the stage for *bad ass*.  I'm not sure it had the right kind of memetic value to spawn the other variants, though.  I wonder when it first became common to use it to refer to a *person* rather than a portion of a person's anatomy.

Comment: Note that 'fat ass' has the same cadence as 'bad ass', which chaos refers to as the idiom's onomatopoeic property. In any case, it certainly is close enough to alliteration to be pleasing to the ear.

Comment: @dotancohen: That isn't actually what I meant, but a good point. :)

Comment: Then what property were you referring to as onomatopoeic?

Comment: But 'fat ass' is a noun phrase while OP surely asks about  compound adjectives/adverbs (apologies to those who don't hold that open compounds exist).

Comment: This is the only line of answering this question that offers an explanation of the connection between the literal meaning of the word and its use as an intensifier.

Comment: @jsw29 But this answer misunderstands the parsing of the OP. The question is not about 'stupid ass' where 'ass' is a noun. It's about 'ass' as a postposed adverb, modifying the adjective, eg 'there is a stupid-ass person', 'ass' is modifying 'stupid', not the other way round.

Comment: @Mitch, yes, granted, that's how the suffix is used, and that's what the question is about. But, for the origin of that usage to be **explained** (as distinct from just noticing and recording that the usage exists), we need some account of why *ass* was selected to play this role. This answer is about something that predates the usage that the question is about but that might be the missing link between using the word in its literal sense and using it as a suffix-intensifier.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

The [Google Books NGram Viewer](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=bad%20ass,badass,fat%20ass,fatass&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=0&smoothing=3) shows "fat ass" with some use since around 1920, while "fatass" has a lower level of use up until 2000 (the latest the chart goes to), and "bad ass" and "badass" seem to start to be used a bit before 1970.

Comment: You do realize that I am going to now waste hours with that thing, don't you?